# How do I get Apache to follow symlinks?

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

In my apache www folder (`/var/www` on ubuntu 10.10) I have:

```
mydir -> /home/user/mydir
```

(that I created with `ln -s`)

Now, if I want to see a listing of the files in `mydir` from the web, I have to give apache the directive `FollowSymLinks`, right?

But where do I put it? In a `.htaccess` file? Where? I tried many ways but I don't understand it...

This is my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    Alias /downloads/ "/root/mydir/"
    <Directory "/root/mydir">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I also tried with an Alias in the config file.. still doesn't work..

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There are two things here:

1. symlinks
2. directory listing

**symlinks**

Assuming `/var/www` is your DocumentRoot for your default virtual host, you should find your default virtual host configuration file (probably `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`) and put it inside that virtual host block, e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
```

If you haven't changed anything, that option should already be there.

**directory listing**

To make Apache list the files in a directory, you need to enable the `Indexes` option too, e.g. change

```
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
```

in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` to:

```
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
```

Or, perhaps a more secure way is to change it to:

```
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Indexes
    </Directory>
```

and put this in `/home/user/mydir/.htaccess`.

```
    Option Indexes
```

**why .htaccess doesn't work**

By default, putting `Options <something>` in an `.htaccess` file won't work because of the other entry in your config file: `AllowOverride None`.

That's why we have to put `AllowOverride Indexes` there.

([AllowOverride documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride))

Comment: look at my config file above...
it doesn't work yet...

Comment: can it be a problem of permissions? I'm root user, I know it's not a good thing to use a system as root, anyway.. I'm root and the directory I symlink to is in the root home /root/mydir..

Comment: Yes.  What error message do you see?  You will need to do `sudo chmod ugo+x /root; sudo chmod ugo+rx /root/mydir` to make it work, and that's probably not a good idea.  Better to move the files somewhere under `/var/www` if you can.

Comment: Whenever you get an error and are asking for help, you should provide the exact error message to us.  And there will be clues in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: sorry I didn't provide error log since it was pretty useless, it said only can't access directory because can't follow symlinks OR because don't have the rights..
So it didn't provide clues, I thought... I'll see if I can fix the permissions, or I'll just move the files..

Comment: Make sure you are not pointing to your home directory when you have it encrypted, i.e. a symbolic link in `/var/www` → `/home/user/directory`. It will produce a huge headache.

Comment: +1 finally a person knows how-to explain configuration changes in understandable manner ...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381371/apache-wont-follow-symlinks-403-forbidden

Comment: Apache 2.4.48 - I found www-data needed access to all parts of the path.  `chmod 755 /home/user` cured it for me but I would not recommend that on a public-facing machine  -

Answer (score 14):

The option must be used like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Usually it's put in Apache configuration (`httpd.conf` or `conf.d/` or `sites-enabled/`) inside a `<Directory>`.

See [`Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options), [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) and [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) in Apache documentation.

Comment: In the case of FollowSymLinks specifically it MUST be inside a Directory structure when within a .conf file. From the Apache current manual "The FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch Options work only in <Directory> sections or .htaccess files."

Comment: Warning: Mixing Options with a + or - with those without is not valid syntax and is likely to cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 14):

With the original (fresh) configuration on Ubuntu 14.04 with apache 2.4.7, there is no need to change anything in *.conf to follow symlinks created under /var/www/html.

But it is necessary that user www-data has access to **ALL** the path of symlink target (even for virtualhosts not only for simlinks). For instance,

```
cd /var/www/html
ln -s /path/to/mirror/cran-mirror cran
```

In this example user www-data (or all users if you want, but can be dangerous) needs **execute** rights all the way to the directory. Need x rights in each of /path, /path/to, and /path/to/mirror. Also needs **Read** permission on the target directory, and, depending of the goal of the directory, maybe user www-data needs write permissions too.

Clue was obtained from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623574

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get this working until installing the autoindex apache module. Out of numerous blog posts and forum posts, no one mentioned it being necessary. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: `mod_autoindex` is for generating directory indexes automatically. OP question is about symlinks functionality, which is enabled by `Options +FollowSymLinks`, as explained above.