# Apache shows "Forbidden" error with "FollowSymLinks"

Tags: apache-http-server

I have been using Apache2 for a long time. Most of the time I use "virtual hosts", but I just had my provider change me from a "shared-ip" to a "fixed-ip" address.

That's when it all went to hell. All they should have done is change my ip-address.

Here is my configuration:

`/etc/httpd/conf` has my `httpd.conf` file. Its last line is

```
Include conf/vhosts.con
```

My `vhosts` file contains:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80  

<VirtualHost *:80>  
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/export/home">
  Options Includes ExecCGI Indexes  
  AddHandler cgi-script .pl  
  AllowOverride AuthConfig  
  Order allow,deny  
  Allow from all  
</Directory>

Include conf/webs/website.com
Include conf/webs/web1.com
```

So each virtual server should be the same with all the permissions – easy, right? And each server is its own file.

web1 is a typical server.. and has access to mysql.

`web1.biz`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName web1.biz
  ServerAlias http://www.web1.biz
  DocumentRoot /export/home/webs/web1/public_html
  ErrorLog /var/log/www/web1/error.log
  TransferLog /var/log/www/web1/transfer.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Website:

This is my main website with access to mysql myaddmin in `/var/www/html/pma`  so I have a link in my `/export/home/webs/website/public_html` to `/var/www/html/pma`. But before they changed my address it worked fine.. with the above configuration.

This is my current configuration but I still get the "Forbidden" error when I try to start `phpmyaddmin`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName website.net
  ServerAlias http://www.website.net
  DocumentRoot /export/home/webs/website/public_html
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.pl index.php
  <Directory />
    Options Includes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride Indexes
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/www/website/error.log
  TransferLog /var/log/www/website/transfer.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Cris. Next time you post, please take a minute to check your formatting. Your post was barely readable before. You can see the source code by clicking [edit]. Thanks!

Comment: What exact error message do you see in /var/log/www/website/error.log?

Comment: the error.log contains: [Thu Aug 02 20:29:59 2012][error][client 66.169.97.xx] Symbolic link not allowed: /export/home/webs/website/public_html/pma

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to this question: https://superuser.com/a/819999/355341

Likely, in your case, you were moved to a new server and the configuration changed (your data were moved, but config files no). If the change is from apache 2.2 to 2.4 there is another issue with Required directive.